# on every row on SELECT Query must lookup to other table

Tags: sql-server-2012, select, subquery

I'm working on Login/Logout System and I'm facing this problem regarding on `SELECT Query`. I have 2 tables namely **dtr_tbl** and **shift_tbl**. In **dtr_tbl** are the logs of the user(login/logout time details) and in **shift_tbl** are the list of shifts available for the users.

**>> dtr_tbl**

[image]

**>> shift_tbl** (*please ignore `dates` on **shifting_timeFr** and **shiftingtimeTo** Columns, just focus on `time`*)

[image]

What I wanted to do is compute the **`TotalHrs`** per **`day`** and per **`shifting_code`**. *(see below my sample sql)*

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    CONVERT(varchar,log_date,101) AS [LogDate],
    MIN(d.login_time) AS [Login],
    MAX(d.logout_time) AS [Logout],
    d.shift_code,
    CASE WHEN MIN(d.login_time) <= -->> validate if `Login` time of user is valid within given `gracetime period` 
    CAST(
        CAST(CONVERT(DATE, -->> extract `Date` only from user's `login` time.
                        DATEADD( 
                                hh,
                                IIF(sh.shifting_LVtime=1,-15,0), -->> check if toggle for LVtime(just ignore this)
                                MIN(d.login_time) -->> current login time of user
                                )) AS DATETIME) + 
        CAST(CONVERT(TIME, -->> extract `Time` only from table `shift_tbl` on `shifting_timeFr` column
                        DATEADD( -->> add `15 minutes` for given `gracetime` period
                                MINUTE,
                                sh.shifting_gracetime, -->> 15 mins given `gracetime` period from shift_tbl
                                sh.shifting_timefr --> from `shift_tbl`
                                )) AS DATETIME) 
        AS DATETIME) THEN
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                    CAST(CONVERT(
                                DATE,
                                MIN(d.login_time)
                                ) AS DATETIME) + 
                    CAST(CONVERT(
                                TIME,
                                sh.shifting_timefr
                                ) AS DATETIME)
            ,MAX(d.logout_time))/60.0
ELSE
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(d.login_time),
                MAX(d.logout_time))/60.0 
END  AS [TotalHrs]
FROM tblDTR d
INNER JOIN tblShiftings sh
ON d.shift_code = sh.shifting_code
WHERE user_id = 'USER1' 
        AND d.log_date
            BETWEEN CAST('03/13/2015' AS datetime) 
                AND CAST('03/23/2015' AS datetime)
GROUP BY 
    d.user_id,
    d.shift_code,
    sh.shifting_gracetime,
    sh.shifting_timefr,
    sh.shifting_timeto,
    sh.shifting_LVtime,
    CONVERT(varchar,d.log_date,101)
ORDER BY LogDate ASC
```

My Sample code above is not working, it only work on **shift_code** with **DS01**, I also want to compute the other **shift_code** from **dtr_tbl**.

**>> Result:**

[image]

thanks.

Comment: `please ignore dates on shifting_timeFr and shiftingtimeTo Columns, just focus on time` Why don't you store it as a `TIME` then?

Comment: Can you script some sample data & DDL of the tables, then i'll take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that MAY cause it: The tables you are showing us are not SELECT * FROM ... are they? I think that in `dtr_tbl`, the `logdate` has a time part that is not 00:00:00 and this causes that in the `WHERE` condition,

```
log_date BETWEEN CAST('03/13/2015' AS datetime) 
             AND CAST('03/23/2015' AS datetime)
```

leads to ie

```
2015-03-23 8:00:05 between 2015-03-13 00:00:00 --true
                       and 2015-03-23 00:00:00 --false
```

thats the only thing i see that could be bad with it as rest of it seems ok to me and i don't see what the problem should be.

PS: It works for DS02 for instance too as can be seen in result set